# Service Component missing in AEM

Tags: eclipse, aem

I am trying to create a project in `Eclipse` using the `AEM Developer Tools` plugin. The project is published in `AEM` server and can be seen in: `Websites` and `CRXDE Lite`.

The project was created using `Maven Archetype-10` in `Eclipse` and the default project has two pages in English and French. When I open the page in the [Site URL](http://localhost:4502/sites.html/content/pen), I get the [end page](http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/pen/en.html), where the message from the `HelloWorldModel` class should be displayed, along with the other text. But I don't get the message from the respective class. Instead, I am getting the following error message:

> org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Cannot find a a file corresponding to class com.pen.mypen.core.models.HelloWorldModel in the repository.

It looks like the `Java` files in the CORE project are not published or are not visible to the web page. But the 3 packages: `Core`, `Apps`, and `Content` are all published and synchronized in `Eclipse`. Is there any way to check if the `Java` package is deployed to `AEM` server? Please guide me to what I am missing here. Please find the error stack trace below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Cannot find a a file corresponding to class com.pen.mypen.core.models.HelloWorldModel in the repository.
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.compiler.SightlyJavaCompilerService.compileRepositoryJavaClass(SightlyJavaCompilerService.java:212)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.compiler.SightlyJavaCompilerService.getInstance(SightlyJavaCompilerService.java:113)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.JavaUseProvider.provide(JavaUseProvider.java:127)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.UseRuntimeExtension.call(UseRuntimeExtension.java:84)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderContextImpl.call(RenderContextImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.apps.pen.components.content.helloworld.SightlyJava_helloworld.render(SightlyJava_helloworld.java:53)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderUnit.render(RenderUnit.java:54)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.evaluateScript(SightlyScriptEngine.java:92)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.eval(SightlyScriptEngine.java:78)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
```

**UPDATE**

- AEM - 6.2
- Eclipse - Luna
- Java - 1.8

Comment: Please see my latest update, that should solve your problem.

Comment: @OliverGebert, thanks for the update. Ameesh answer is working fine for me. Do you think your solution is better and per standard? If yes, then I will implement and test your solution. Please advise.

Comment: Adding the sling model impl dependencies is rather bad, as you should stick to the API and not to the specific implementation. Same is with geronimo. You should not care which bundle is exposing your dependencies, that might lead to further problems if these bundles are updated with a hotfix. I would prefer my own approach, because I don't like to interfere too much with the standard product, but I would not say my solution is "better"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using SlingModels the `javax.inject` is exposed by the `org.apache.sling.models.api`

Can you check your pom for the SlingModel dependencies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION_NUMBER</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.impl</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION_NUMBER</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Check the VERSION_NUMBER you are using and then in `/system/console/bundles` verify that the same version bundle is present and Active.

With AEM 6.x the Sling Model bundles are available by default. The 6.0 will have a lower version 1.0.x. Fixing the version either by updating the pom or installing the SlingModel bundles with version VERSION_NUMBER fix your issue.

> Update for 6.2

For 6.2 with models with version 1.2.2 use following in dependencies -

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

`geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec` is the one that is exposing `javax.inject` in sling models 1.2.2

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried with the impl dependency. I again added the above dependency with version 1.2.2 and with api as 1.0.0. It is not working. I am still getting the error. When I change api to 1.2.2, I am getting the compiler error in HelloWorldModel class where the Inject annotation is part of the api lib 1.0.0 and not part of 1.2.2. FYI, I am using AEM 6.2. Models. api and impl bundles are active in /system/console/bundle sections. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Please see updates to my answer above, this should resolve your issue. I was able to setup sling model with above dependencies successfully on AEM 6.2

Let me know in case you need any further information.

Comment: I tired the new library earlier but alone. I did not add impl. Thats why it did not work. After adding all three libraries in the pom.xml, I am able to deploy the bundle and its active in the webconsole. Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following things:

1. `http://SERVER:PORT/system/console/bundles` shows all the java bundles that are installed on your AEM machine. Check if your bundle is listed there. If not then it could not be installed => check the error log
2. If your bundle is listed there, check if it is status is `active`, if not there might be missing dependencies or stuff like that. => click the bundle name to see more details what went wron, also check the error log.
3. If the status is `active`, click on the bundle and see if the package that contains your java class is listed in the `Exported Packages` section.
4. If the package is listed, you might need to check the error log (again).

**UPDATE (because of AEM 6.2):**

The problem with your project is, that with AEM versions prior to 6.2, there was a dependency to `javax.inject` version `0` whereas now they need version 1 and that's not reflected in the `pom.xml`.
Just add this to your `pom.xml` of the `core` project - **that's the only change** you'll have to do:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

and everything will work. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. The status of the bundle is INSTALLED. There is an error under Imported Packages. Error - javax.inject,version=[0.0,1) -- Cannot be resolved. Only this is in red. Can you please guide me on the Sightly code. I have not written anything apart from the archetype-generated code. I am just trying to deploy the default project into AEM and see if its coming up well.

Comment: Which AEM/CQ-version and Service Pack is your machine running with?

Comment: I am using AEM 6.2. I tried to rebuild the project after adding the dependency in pom file. I can see the class javax.inject under the org...scripting.java 2.0.12. Again the bundle was not installed properly in AEM. I am getting the same error that inject.class cannot be resolved. I updated the lib with version 2.0.14, but I don't see the javax.inject class in the library. Even after rebuilding with 2.0.14 version, I get the same error and my bundle is not Active.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my solution which will be helpful.
Tested on AEM 6.2 working perfect.

In core pom.xml file add Import-Package tag with "**javax.inject;version=0.0.0,***" inside "**org.apache.felix**" plugin tag.

Following is the sample :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <!--
         <Embed-Dependency>
            artifactId1,artifactId2;inline=true
         </Embed-Dependency>
      -->
      <!-- Import any version of javax.inject, to allow running on multiple versions of AEM -->
      <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>

      <Sling-Model-Packages>
         com.next.sample_test_impl.core
      </Sling-Model-Packages>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```